# How to access joined table attributes in Rails3?

Tags: sql, ruby, join, ruby-on-rails-3, relation

I am having trouble accessing the attributes of a join in Rails3.

There is two models/tables : Place and Address. One place can have many addresses (i.e. a specific street address, a "corner of" address, etc.). For historical reasons, the tables do not follow standard Rails conventions:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name :PLACE
 set_primary_key :PLACE_ID
 has_many :addresses, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => :PLACE_ID
end
```

and

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name :ADDRESS
 set_primary_key :ADDRESS_ID
 belongs_to :place, :foreign_key => "PLACE_ID"
end
```

I am trying to get all the addresses for one particular place:

```
pa = Place.joins(:addresses).where(:place_id => 68)
```

The SQL that is generated looks fine:

```
pa.to_sql

"SELECT [PLACE].* FROM [PLACE] INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] ON [ADDRESS].[PLACE_ID] = [PLACE].[PLACE_ID] WHERE ([PLACE].[place_id] = 68)"
```

The returned relation also has the right size, as that particular place has 6 addresses associated with it:

```
irb(main):050:0> pa.size
=> 6
```

However, the returned relation pa only contains the attributes of the Place model, it doesn't contain any attributes of the Address model.

Pre Rails3 I used to do a find_by_sql and could access the attributes of the two joined table easily in the returned Hash, however I simply cannot get Rails3 to reveal to me the 
attributes from the joined Address table.

I must be missing something very basic here - anyone care to point it out to me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for includes instead of joins. This will do exactly what you want.

```
pa = Place.includes(:addresses).where(:place_id => 68)
```

If you want to order by address.street_name in your comment to captaintokyo's answer. You can do then add an order like this:

```
pa = Place.includes(:addresses).where(:place_id => 68).order(:addresses => :street_name)
```

The difference between the two includes and joins is that `joins` will join the supplied models to the produced query for the sake matching in a where clause. As opposed to `includes` which, in addition to adding joining the model, will also include that model's fields in the select statement.

So to recap:

```
Place.includes(:addresses).where(:place_id => 68)
```

produces this:

```
"SELECT [PLACE].*, [ADDRESS].* FROM [PLACE] INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] ON [ADDRESS].[PLACE_ID] = [PLACE].[PLACE_ID] WHERE ([PLACE].[place_id] = 68)"
```

while

```
Place.joins(:addresses).where(:place_id => 68)
```

produces this:

```
"SELECT [PLACE].* FROM [PLACE] INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] ON [ADDRESS].[PLACE_ID] = [PLACE].[PLACE_ID] WHERE ([PLACE].[place_id] = 68)"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need in arel way is just like

```
pa = Place.joins(:addresses).where(:place_id => 68).select('PLACE.*, ADDRESS.*')
```

and then you will get all the attributes in pa for these two tables.

But I am wondering if there is a better design for you:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name :PLACE
 set_primary_key :PLACE_ID
 has_many :addresses, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => :PLACE_ID
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name :ADDRESS
 set_primary_key :ADDRESS_ID
 belongs_to :place, :foreign_key => "PLACE_ID"

 scope :with_place, lambda {|place_id| joins(:place).where(:place_id => place_id).select('ADDRESS.*, PLACE.*')}
end

addresses = Address.with_place(68)
```

or just use the delegate function if you need to use Place instance at the same time

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name :ADDRESS
 set_primary_key :ADDRESS_ID
 belongs_to :place, :foreign_key => "PLACE_ID"

 delegate :any_place_attribute, :to => :place
end

address = Address.find(x)
address.any_place_attribute #you can access PLACE table attribute now
```